# Disable all keys

Tags: android, root

I'm making an app for my school. This app needs to disable the phone for a certain amount of time (one hour). This means that I have to disable all hardware keys.

It only has to be able to run on one phone, which is running on android Jelly Bean. After some research, I found out that it I'm unable to accomplish this without making a Home Screen app. But I was wondering if it is able to accomplish this with root? I have rooted my device. If yes, how am I able to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to study about **Kiosk Mode**. Kiosk mode applications are applications that lock the device and do not allow the user to run any other application other than the kiosk application.